# Apache behind corporate proxy

Tags: php, apache, curl, proxy, sdk

I'm developing a php application. I'm using wamp and I'm behind a corporate proxy. I'm using [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) to authenticate [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager). I need to curl google geocoding api, in order to do this I used the following settings that are working:

```
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:3128');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
```

I'd like to find a way to avoid setting those options for CURL. I believe I can play with Apache setting, but I'm not sure. The reasons I need to find this solution are:

1. In production env there will be no such a proxy (at the moment the above options are used only if the environment variable is set to DEV env, but still: it's not the best solution)
2. If I want to use 3rd party SDK (such as facebook php sdk), those are internally using CURL but they do not necessarily expose method to change CURL options (for example facebook sdk doesn't). I don't want to change the SDK source code to fit my proxy

### What I tried:

So far I turned on proxy_module on apache and I added the following line on httpd.conf, but with no success

```
ProxyRemote * http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

I still can't access the internet. I googled a lot, but I couldn't find a solution, any ideas?

I could find many people talking about the same issue, but I didn't find any comprehensive solution, for this reason I raise a bounty.

### What I found:

There is [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29280) in which I found: But I'm not sure if this will work for curl and anyway I can't find how to modify the php.ini

> [2010-12-20 14:03 UTC]
>   jani@php.net
>   -Summary: changing the default http-wrapper
>   +Summary: Add php.ini option to set default proxy for wrappers
>   -Package: Feature/Change Request
>   +Package: Streams related
>   -PHP Version: 5CVS
>   +PHP Version: *

and

> [2011-04-05 11:29 UTC] play4fun_82 at yahoo dot com Hi, i have the
>   same problem. My solution was to pass through proxy server with cntml
>   tunneling tool. You configure cntml proxy to forward http request
>   received on local host on a port to destination with proper
>   authentication.
>
> And in pear u just configure
>
> > pear config-set http_proxy 127.0.0.1:3128
>
> 3128 - is port configuret in cntlm(it can be any other free port).

Thanks very much

Comment: While I can't prove it, I would suspect that this isn't possible (or at the very least - isn't desirable) as you would get different results depending on how PHP was invoked. PHP on the command line would _not_ rely on any Apache settings; a PHP script being served from Apache _does_ have access to some settings set by Apache.

Comment: Ok, so is it possible through PHP setting? Environment variable? Install a 3rd party app that make apache/php dialogue with my proxy?

Comment: Weird thing, setting the environment variable http_proxy on the command line with `set http_proxy=http://192.168.61.25:3128` works flawlessly with cURL in PHP; if it is set in the Apache environment via `SetEnv http_proxy http://192.168.61.25:3128` it is present, but ignored.

Comment: Thanks, could you add more details? I tried set http_proxy in the terminal, but it still not working. "Where" should I run the command?

Comment: I used it like this: `C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\test>set https_proxy=https://192.168.61.25:3128` and `C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\test>"\Program Files\xampp\php\php" curltest.php` in a DOS window. But the command line is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this](http://mon-beulogue.com/en/2013/10/10/php-behind-a-proxy-server/) article I was about to throw in the towel, but there is actually an easy solutiuon. I had to play with windows environment variable, at the end setting a system variable to https_proxy=https://localhost:3128 worked! Before it was not working because I was setting it to 127.0.0.1:3128. Run the command

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | find /i "proxyserver"
```

then copy/paste the answer in the system variable and now it's working!!

Answer (score 2):

You're saying you want this functionality on WAMP, for your development computer only, right? The SDK's work without modification in production, so you can just take advantage of your Window's Host file to redirect requests.

[Here's a walkthrough](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/modify-your-hosts-file).

Comment: Thanks, you're right! But could you please add some more details? I know what is the host file and I already changed it in the past, but I don't know how to modify it for my purpose. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do it through proxy tools like Proxifier(http://www.proxifier.com).

AFAIK, they can capture traffic from selected applications and redirect to a proxy automatically.

Not a perfect solution but should be useful on dev machine.