# PHP CURL is using a environment variable that I didn't set

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I'm using WAMP. In the past weeks I struggled a lot to make php and curl work behind a corporate proxy, finally I did it: [Apache behind corporate proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821647/apache-behind-corporate-proxy)

The problem is that now I can't make them work at home! (of course initially they were working at home without proxy). When I run a CURL command from php I get the following error: `Curl error: Failed to connect to localhost port 3128`

I removed all the environment variable https_proxy and http_proxy, on apache I removed the "proxy_module", on IE I removed the proxy, now when I run the following command there are no results:

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | find /i "proxyserver"
```

It seems that CURL is taking the proxy configuration from somewhere in the environment variable, in fact if I add the applicative code:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
```

then everything is working fine (but I don't want to change the applicative code). Where else can I look for the proxy confing?

Thanks very much

Comment: see what a `var_dump(CURLOPT_PROXY);` does right before you `curl`

Comment: result is 'int 10004'

Comment: ok, nice, search your project, config and ini files for 10004, see if you can find anything.

Comment: I've just got you to search for the constant code which wouldn't have turned up anything useful, apologies. search for `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY` instead, up to the point, and see if that brings you anything. You could `var_dump($ch);` as well and see if you can spot a proxy value sitting in there.